# OS X codesign nested code is modified or invalid

Tags: macos, qt4, codesign

Qt4 application with bundle structure like that:

```
QtCore.framework/
    QtCore  -> Versions/Current/QtCore
    Resources    -> Versions/Current/Resources
    Versions/
        4/
            QtCore
            Resources/
                Info.plist
        Current  -> 4

codesign --verbose --force --deep --sign "Certificate Name" Test.app
```

Result: Test.app: signed bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [...]
"Certificate Name" is Comodo code sign certificate

```
codesign --verify -vvvv Test.app
Test.app: nested code is modified or invalid

codesign --verbose --verify Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework
Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework: valid on disk
Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework: does not satisfy its designated Requirement
```

p.s. I have tried to sign manually all framework/dylib without option --deep and the same result.

Answer (score 0):

create a folder called A inside versions with same contents of 4, change the symbolic links to the A folder especially current->A

try signing now and it may sign. But the problem may be with the binary, it will use a different framework than A, which you can check with otool -L (take care big L and not small l)

to change it, you need to use install_name_tool

good luck and have fun